# How to retrieve the model name within the table class in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am inside a `ModelTable` and I need the `Model` name. For example: in case of `EventTable` I need to know the model it instantiates - `Event`.

Internally the following function already instantiates an correct `Model`:

```
class EventTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function findBySomething($something)
    {
       // Will return a Event
       return $this->createQuery('s')->fetchOne();
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do:

```
class EventTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function findBySomething($something)
    {
       $modelName = $this->getModelName();
       echo "I will create a ".$modelName; // Will display Event
       return $this->createQuery('s')->fetchOne();
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the model name from inside a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of options available for each Table (Doctrine/Table.php):

```
protected $_options = array(
     'name'           => null,
     'tableName'      => null,
     'sequenceName'   => null,
     'inheritanceMap' => array(),
     'enumMap'        => array(),
     'type'           => null,
     'charset'        => null,
     'collate'        => null,
     'treeImpl'       => null,
     'treeOptions'    => array(),
     'indexes'        => array(),
     'parents'        => array(),
     'joinedParents'  => array(),
     'queryParts'     => array(),
     'versioning'     => null,
     'subclasses'     => array(),
);
```

So you can retrieve the model name using:

```
$this->getOption('name');
```